# python CAS login portal with unknown redirect url

Tags: python, http

I am able to login most url with python. This url given username and password I am not able to as I dont understand where the url link is coming from . I have spent so much time on this.  Here is the sequence from developer tools.

```
GET --> https:/abc.com/
from response header I see eTag="1234xyz"

GET --> https:/cas1.abc.com/cas/login?service=abc.com/webapi/j_spring_cas_security_check?redirect-url=abcdef123xyz
response header provides --> Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A1234; Path=/cas; Secure; HttpOnly

GET --> https:/someother url;jsessionid=A1234

POST --> https:/someother url;jsessionid=A1234?service=abc.com/webapi/efg?redirect-url=abcdef123xyz
```

The mystery is where is this --> redirect-url=abcdef123xyz  coming from to form the final POST request

By the way this is CAS login

Comment: Is it your server? Is it python server?

Comment: it is my company server,